# High RAM use on Win7 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have a HP DV4-2126TX with Win7 OS. It has 2GB RAM.
After startup and while idle 50% of the RAM is in use.
I tried disabling all the unwanted process at startup but the problem persists. Here is a list of what is running in startup:

- Intel Common user Interface (3 processes)
- Catalyst Control Centre
- Alps pointing device driver
- HP Quick Launch Buttons
- hpWuSchd
- HP Wireless assistant
- Nero AG NeroCheck
- Virtual Clone Drive
- MalwareBytes Antimalware
- IDT Audio
- MSE
- Java Platform Updater 2.0
- Bluetooth Software
- Rainmeter

Previously my laptop would consume around 38% RAM when idle but now  it consumes 50% when idle. What should I do to get back the available RAM?

Comment: I too have 2 gigs of RAM and 50% is always occupied, kill HP Quick launch assistant and Virtual Clone Drive and Java Updater.

Comment: Also note that Win7 does have a lot of services running, those all add up with their RAM usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hate to break it to you, but this is normal. If you want to see what processes are consuming the RAM, feel free to take a look with task manager or resource manager, but there will not be much that you can do.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7, I'd recommend 4GB of RAM. Check if you have 2x1gb or 1x2gb and upgrade accordingly, it should cost $15-20